# Have Android SDK into a tablet with honeycomb?

Tags: android, sdk, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet

I want to know if exists any form to have the Android SDK into a tablet with Honeycomb.
I ask this because I´ve a tablet with honeycomb and I like to programm into this device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to developed on an Android table with AIDE. See more details here https://plus.google.com/101304250883271700981

Answer (score 1):

Running IDE in your tablet? This wouldn't be very practical. Anyway, you could use [Android Scripting Engine](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) to edit and run primitive scripts on your tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SDK here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

And there is no need to install anything into your tablet. Just download the SDK for your PC and start developing.

Comment: I want to develop only using my tablet, no PC or Mac.

Comment: Like running IDE in your tablet? This wouldn't be very practical. Anyway, you could use [Android Scripting Engine](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) to edit and run primitive scripts on your tablet.

Comment: I believe in this will be more practical that anything else. Obviously, the IDE for Honeycomb must to had its own "Android Emulator".

Comment: This idea of develop is totally perfect for anyone that had an Acer Iconia Tab, because this tablet has an normal USB port, so it supports a normal keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Writing replies like -not very practical- doesnt help, that is something relative to each of us, we have tablets with good hardware and comfortable keyboard docks, not to mention quad core tablets with tegra3 that are comming in dicember. I still don't understand why Google has no SDK for Android OS yet. Android already runs great even on PCs (via de Android x86 project).

In fact, i'm a developer and i use some interesting applications to develop from muy tablet, i recommend you to visit [JavaIDEdroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.t_arn.JavaIDEdroid&feature=also_installed) and [Terminal IDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) wich are some examples of projects that are far from being Eclipse but already let us develop applications for Android and also for Java SE. There also more resources in the XDA forum (look for 'Asus Transformer' for example) even if those projects are not enough, there are guides to install Ubuntu dual boot and other posible solutions to your problem.